# comparing elements of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, comparison

I am a beginner in C++ and I am able to add words dynamically from a file to a vector array, but I want to take each word and find out how many times that word occurs in the file and print the word only once and list the line number of each time it occurs. I am not sure where to go from my vector of words. Is there a way to compare each string element? Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>#include 
using namespace std;
int main() {
ifstream inFile, testStream;
ofstream outFile; 
vector<string> words; 
string temp, choice, inFileName, outFileName, word, trash; 
int idx = 0, lineCount = 0;
bool outputOpened = false;
stringstream wordStream;    
for (;;) {  
    cout << "Options: "<< endl << "1. Index" << endl << "2. Quit" << endl 
    << "Please enter an option: ";
    getline(cin, temp);
    choice.resize(temp.length());
    transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), choice.begin(), ::toupper);
    if (choice.compare("INDEX") == 0 || choice.compare("1") == 0) {
        do {
            inFileName.clear();
            cout << "Index Program" << endl
            << "==============" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Input file name: ";
            getline(cin, inFileName);
            inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());
            if(inFile.fail()) {
                cout << "Can't open file" << endl;
                if(inFile.bad()) {
                    cout << "Bad" << endl;
                }
                inFile.clear();
            }
        }
        while (!inFile.is_open());
        do {
            cout << "Output file name: ";
            getline( cin, outFileName);
            testStream.clear();
            testStream.open(outFileName.c_str());
            if(testStream.good()) {
                cout << "That file already exists, try again" << endl;
                testStream.clear();
                testStream.close();
            }
            else {
                testStream.clear();
                testStream.close();
                outFile.open(outFileName.c_str());
                if (outFile.good()) {
                    outputOpened = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (!outputOpened);
        while (inFile.peek() != EOF) {
            getline(inFile,word, ' ');

            lineCount++;


            words.push_back(word); // now the vector 'words' contains all words in the file
        }
    for (idx = 0; idx < words.size(); idx++) {
        outFile << words[idx] << endl;
    }   
}
else if (choice.compare("QUIT") == 0 || choice.compare("2") == 0) {
return 0;
}
else {
cout << temp << " is an unrecognized option, please try again" << endl;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a question, using the map container, which I did successfully, how would I incorporate the line number that each word is on?? If I added a counter in the while loop it would only increment after each word in the file, not each new line.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

1. instead of `vector`, consider using a `map` - this will allow you to *associate* a count with a given word
2. When inserting a word, see if the map contains it, if it does, increment the count, else insert a new entry with a count of 1.
3. At the end, iterate through the map and print the word and the count

On your specific problem. `std::string` has `operator==` implemented, so you can simply compare for equality, e.g.

```
std::string f("foo");
std::string b("bar");

if (f == b)
  std::cout << "foobar" << std::endl;
```

Some other hints:

Use the stream operations to read a word at a time, rather than `peek()` for EOF, something like:

```
// assume fin is a file input stream
std::string word;

while(fin >> word)
{
  if (!word.empty())
  {
    // do stuff with word...
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you! Im sure I can use that while loop and I will start studying maps. We haven't talked about maps in our class but my professor doesn't mind us using other things

Comment: @BryanSmith, well, if the requirement is that you use a vector (and not map), then you can kind of emulate it, however you need to store a simple structure which has a string and a count (you can for example use `std::pair`). Then as you add a word, search through the vector to find the word (using the `operator==`), and increment the count, else insert a new entry at the end.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're trying to achieve there is a better way: [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/). You use a map (just like in the example from the link) and each time you want to add a new element you first search if it exists. If it does not then you initialize it with 1.

```
yourMap[yourString]=1;
```

If the string already exists then you increment that counter:

```
yourMap[yourString]=1+yourMap[yourString];
```

Comment: you can simply pre-increment, no need for the second lookup. (i.e. `++yourMap[yourString]`) - in theory, you shouldn't need to even see if it exists or not (and any way, if it does not exist, you should initialize with count of 1.)

Comment: @Nim Yes. It should be initialized with 1. Corrected

Comment: Thanks a lot! all of your comments are much appreciated